# Soundness and Completeness of extended resolutionproof

Tags: logic

The question concerns the resolution proof in the propositional logic.
Always active:
for all  and  is valid:
( ∨ ) ∧ (′ ∨ ¬) ≡ ( ∨ ) ∧ (′ ∨ ¬) ∧ ( ∨ ′)

1. now the proof gets extended with
   (φ∨u∨¬v)∧(ψ∨¬u∨v) ≡ (φ∨u∨¬v)∧(ψ∨¬u∨v)∧(φ∨ψ)
2. now the proof gets extended with
   (φ∨u) ≡ (φ∨u)∧(φ∨¬u)
3. now the proof gets extended with
   (φ∨u)∧(ψ∨¬u)∧(χ∨u∨¬u) ≡ (φ∨u)∧(ψ∨¬u)∧(χ∨u∨¬u)∧(φ∨ψ∨χ)

only one extension is active at a time.
How do I show the soundness and completeness for each of the extended systems?

Comment: Step 2 is not a logical equivalence since $\neg (\varphi \lor \neg u) \models \varphi \lor u$.